# Why is that for a pointer *p, p[0] is the address stored at p and p[1] is the address of p itself?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, undefined-behavior, dereference

The code

```
int n = 25;  
int *p = &n;  
printf("%x\n %d\n %x\n", p, p[0], p[1]);
```

returns:

```
\<adress-of-p  
25  
\<adress-of-p>
```

Of course I would never do this but in K&R states that

> "if pa is a pointer, expressions may use it with a subscript; pa[i] is identical to *(pa+i).

so I was curious.

Comment: undefined behavior for incorrect `printf()` conversion specifiers.

Comment: It's not printing the address of `p`. The first output is the contents of `p` interpreted as an `int`.

Comment: Logically: `p[1]` is undefined behavior so it could be anything. It doesn't have a meaning. It can be `p` as it happens to be in your case, or maybe 42, or maybe the phone number of the White House, or perhaps accessing it causes a pizza to be ordered online. - Technically: Likely the compiler decided to store `p` in memory directly after `n`. (By the way, `<address-of-p>` is actually `<address-of-n>`.)

Comment: Did you mean to use `&(p[1]) == &(*(p+1)) == p+1`? This gives the address just beyond the end of `n` (since adding a number to a pointer adds that number times the size of the pointed value's type).

Comment: no, i was just messing with pointers while reading K&R and found it interesting - thanks for all the answers and sorry if its a dumb question

Comment: Danserk, what compiler are you using and what warnings are enabled?

Comment: gcc on linux with no particular warnings @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @Danserk You may find '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion'  illuminating and help you find trouble faster than posting SO.

Comment: will sure do @chux-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
printf("%x\n %d\n %x\n", p, p[0], p[1]);
```

invokes undefined behavior by two reasons.

The first one is that to output a pointer you should use a correct conversion specifier. The second one is that you may not dereference a pointer like this `p[1]` that does not point to a valid object.

Instead you could write for example

```
printf("%p\n %d\n %p\n", ( void * )p, p[0], ( void * )( p + 1 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you evaluate `p[1]` in your code, you are invoking undefined behavior so your program can do anything.

It is undefined behavior because `p` points at `n` which is just a single integer, not an array of integers.  So `p[0]` is `n`, but `p[1]` is undefined.  Basically this is an array overflow bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behaviour, because it dereferences a pointer that doesn't point to anything.

The particular symptoms you have experienced are consistent with reading the next variable in the function

Answer (score 1):

The p[n] syntax is syntactic sugar for *(p + n).

So p[0] is *(p + 0), which is *p, and since p points to n, *p is the value of n, which is 25.

Now, p[1] is *(p + 1).  So in theory what you would get is the next integer in memory following n.  In this particular case, the next thing in memory happened to be p itself, which is the address of n.  (Note that this isn't guaranteed, your compiler just chose to arrange things that way.)

Comment: `p[n]` binds tighter than `*(p + n)`.